# Упрощение проверки принадлежности значения указанному диапазону чиесл

Tags: python

Есть строка, надо сделать что бы было от 1000 до 1100. Можно как-то проще реализовать это?
Вот как сделал я:

```
if score >= 1000 and score <= 1100
```

Comment: чтото не то вы написали. меньше 1000 и больше 1100. знаки сравнения перепутали.

Comment: упс... спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно еще так:

```
if 1000 <= score <= 1100:
```

но если у тебя в `score` находится строка и тебе нужно проверить, что она попадает в заданный диапазон, то и и сравнивать нужно со строками

```
if '1000' <= score <= '1100':
```

В твоем примере так же нужно расставить кавычки

Answer (score 1):

if 1000<= score <= 1100: